# What could be causing 'Schedule matching query does not exist' error in Django and how to solve it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am having a problem with my code. It returns error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/davep/Desktop/a/Water_management/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/davep/Desktop/a/Water_management/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/davep/Desktop/a/Water_management/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/davep/Desktop/a/Water_management/employee/views.py", line 159, in areawise_orders
    schedule = Schedule.objects.get(vehicle=vehicle, day=day)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/davep/Desktop/a/Water_management/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/davep/Desktop/a/Water_management/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 415, in get   
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
database.models.Schedule.DoesNotExist: Schedule matching query does not exist.
```

this is my query file https://www.mediafire.com/file/oh0wgkxzcmhu6b7/query.py/file sorry im newbie

remove that error log